# Determine the quotient $\mathbb{Z}^3\big/ A\mathbb{Z}^3$ with Smith normal form

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, smith-normal-form

I found the Smith normal form of a matrix $A$ to be

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0\\
0 & 4 & 0\\
0&0& 8
\end{pmatrix}$$

Can I conclude now that $\mathbb{Z}^3\big/ A\mathbb{Z}^3=\mathbb{Z}^3\big/ B\mathbb{Z}^3$?

And is it right to calculate $\mathbb{Z}^3\big/ B\mathbb{Z}^3=(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})\big/ (\mathbb{Z}\times4\mathbb{Z}\times8\mathbb{Z})=\{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: More exactly you can conclude $\;\mathbf Z^3/A\mathbf Z^3\color{red}{\simeq}\mathbf Z^3/B\mathbf Z^3$. Your calculation is correct (up to an isomorphism).

Comment: You're welcome!